# polymorphic queries in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I try to simplify my question, I have class A :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class A {

    @Field
    private String a;
    ....
}
```

and class B which extends class A:

```
@Entity 
@Indexed
public class B extends A {


    @Field
    private String b;
    ....
}
```

another class C which extends A :

```
@Entity 
@Indexed
public class C extends A {


    @Field
    private String c;
    ....
}
```

My problem is, when I do polymorphic queries like :

```
Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("a").matching(a).createQuery();
```

It works very fine, no problem, but when the field is b or c like :

Q`uery query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("b").matching(b).createQuery();`

I have an exception : 
org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to find field b in C
Is there any solution to this, or should I do non polymorphic queries ? May be I have a mistake somewhere. 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Private fields are not inherited and are not part of polymorphism.

Comment: Not true. I don't think this is my problem because it said : Unable to find field b in C ! and not a in B or C

Comment: And in which class are these queries defined?

Comment: yes its definitely going to complain about column b because its specific to entity B. If the purpose of second query is to only retrieve "b" column data then please consider reworking your HQL or criteria to be more fine grained i.e. query entity B. This will save you some performance as well since you are not querying for entire hierarchy.

Comment: it is hibernate search DSL (Lucene) and not HQL or criteria. This works for HQL or Criteria.

Comment: I have about 50 subclasses I don't want to write a search method for every subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically hitting a limitation of the query DSL. At the moment it only supports the creation of queries for a single indexed type. See also [HSEARCH-1851](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1793).

As a workaround you can revert to writing native Lucene queries. Polymorphic queries should work.

If you want to use the DSL you need to create a `QueryBuilder` instance for the specific subclass you want to target.

Comment: Thanks Hardy the answer is clear, I wanted just to know if it was possible or not. I've made some conditions before creating queries related to each specific subclass.

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same problem, use lucene TermQuery :

```
org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery("field", "term"));
luceneBooleanQuery.add(termQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

if a field is numeric (int, double, ...) use lucene NumericRangeQuery :

```
NumericRangeQuery<Double> numericQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange("numericField", minRange, maxRange,  true, true);
luceneBooleanQuery.add(numericQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```